# how to get OC from the origin github

Tags: openshift

I am trying to do a sample application in openshift and read that we have to download openshift CLI from https://github.com/openshift/origin..
How can i do that? I tried downloading the source code ; but not sure  how to get OC from that. if i download the project , will it be just the source code? Is there a way to get OC CLI from this github link
Ultimately I  need openshift CLI so that i can invoke commands like oc get pods etc
What is the ideal way to get OC CLI

Comment: https://www.okd.io/download.html

Comment: Also see https://cookbook.openshift.org/accessing-an-openshift-cluster/where-can-i-download-the-openshift-command-line-tool.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the compiled oc binaries on the assets section of the [releases page](https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases).

You can find corresponding versions of the oc client under each release tag.

The linux oc binaries for 3.11 OKD are [here](https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/download/v3.11.0/openshift-origin-client-tools-v3.11.0-0cbc58b-linux-64bit.tar.gz).

OpenShift Enterprise customers can find the links to the OpenShift 3.11 Enterprise binaries on access.redhat.com [here](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/290/ver=3.11/rhel---7/3.11.82/x86_64/product-software).